# Throughput for GATT read, write, and notify

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, throughput

[All BLE devices use GATT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy#Software_model)
in which device #1 basically reads and writes device #2's "characteristics".
Additionally, #2 can notify #1 regarding a characteristic change.

On this GATT stack, I want to send about 100 kB from a Texas Instruments CC2652 device to an Android phone,
and have used [this throughput example](https://github.com/TexasInstruments/ble_examples/tree/simplelink_cc13x2_26x2_sdk-5.10)
to push the "overhead-included 2 Mbps" theoretical limit.

If my understanding of the code is correct, Texas Instruments is just doing a "notification" ("GATT_Notification(connHandle, &noti, 0x00)")
for a characteristic ("Toggle_Throughput Characteristic Value") in its GATT table to achieve this.

This notification uses a ~250 B buffer (in the "noti" structure) for maximum throughput but, surprisingly to me,
the GAAT characteristic used here by Texas Instruments is only a one-byte field.

Am I understanding this right?  If I had not seen this example code, I would have thought that any notification about one
byte of data would in principle just tell me to look at that byte, so my throughput could be limited by one-byte
parcelization...  Would my using a characteristic size larger than one byte improve throughput here?

GATT reading or GATT writing of this one-byte characteristic would have lower throughput than GATT notifying, right?

Comment: I would assume the characteristic initially contains one byte or something. Not that each notification would be limited to one byte, as that would be extremely slow.

Comment: @Emil Yes, it seems like notify has more "power" than the characteristic it notifies about, but I am hoping an Android BLE expert might comment (or even answer) about whether this notify method is good for throughput (or, more intuitively, should I switch the roles and make CC2652 "write without response" to a 250B characteristic on my Android phone?).

Comment: Notifications and Write Without Response are equivalent from a performance point of view. Assuming LE Data Length Extension is supported with max size, 244 bytes would be optimal. L2CAP CoC is another good alternative.

Comment: @Emil The git code I referenced above seems to be using "handle value notifications" with 244B payload + 4B L2CAP header + 3B ATT header, but I don't receive a single bit in the Android app I am building (even though I have the standard setCharacteristicNotification and writeDescriptor GATT procedure)...any chance you know what I am missing?  I am guessing I need to use a lower-level "ATT protocol" with periodic WRITE_REQ 0x12 (or WRITE_CMD 0x52), but does the Android SDK offer this?

Comment: If you are sending notifications, then ATT_HANDLE_VALUE_NTF has opcode 0x1b. These will be received by Android if setCharacteristicNotification is set.

Comment: @Emil After further experiments, all I needed was just a requestMtu() call to finally receive the notifications, hooray! I am surprised that a working MTU wasn't set automatically (and am not sure which of my two devices is behaving badly), but the requestMTU call (no matter what MTU value I pick) somehow straightens this out.